# Recycler View Divider Item not showing in Dark Mode

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have the following code which creates a divider line between the items in a recycler view. It works just fine in normal mode, but when switching to dark mode the lines are no longer visible. How to fix this?

```
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(DividerItemDecoration(this@MainActivity, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL))
```

Comment: add a view into your adapter item with background color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options to solve your issue:

1. Set custom drawable for each theme (dark/light) by using function [dividerItemDecoration.setDrawable()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/DividerItemDecoration#setDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable))
2. Override android listDivider attribute for each theme (dark/light)

for second option, you can modify your dark mode divider color (for example in file `themes.xml`) like this

```
<style name="MyAppTheme" parent="Some.Base.Theme.NightMode">
    <item name="android:listDivider">@color/my_divider_color_darkmode</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Can't the colors be defined in themes.xml and themes.xml (night) so that only one values/style.xml file would be required, i.e. both colors having the same name @color/my_divider_color?

Comment: in that case, I think you do not need values/styles.xml , just add `<item name="android:listDivider">...</item>` in your themes.xml and values-night/themes.xml

Comment: Wow, thanks! It works! I only had to define it in themes.xml (dark) since it already works in the light theme. Please edit your answer with this solution and I will mark it as the accepted answer. It's the simplest and cleanest solution of all.

Answer (score 2):

You could try with custom drawable as divider. Like:

```
val recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerView)
    val drawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, R.drawable.line_divider, null)
    drawable?.let {
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(CustomDivider(this,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,it))
    }
```

CustomDivider class looks like below:

```
class CustomDivider(context: Context, orientation: Int, private val mDrawable:Drawable): DividerItemDecoration(context,orientation) {
override fun onDrawOver(c: Canvas, parent: RecyclerView, state: RecyclerView.State) {
    val left = parent.paddingStart
    val right = parent.width - parent.paddingEnd
    val childCount = parent.childCount
    for (i in 0 until childCount){

        val child = parent.getChildAt(i)
        val params = child.layoutParams as RecyclerView.LayoutParams
        val top = child.bottom + params.bottomMargin
        val bottom = top + mDrawable.intrinsicHeight
        mDrawable.setBounds(left,top, right, bottom)
        mDrawable.draw(c)
    }
}
}
```

And the drawble which is used as divider line:
line_divider.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<size
    android:width="1dp"
    android:height="1dp" />
<solid android:color="#D3D3D3" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the problem is that in dark mode, your divider is the same color as your background, so the divider is 'invisible'?

Another solution could be: have a layout for a single item (which I assume you have already) of your recycler view and add your divider at the end of this single item. Then in resources define the style of your divider where you pass the color of your divider and have two different colors for light/dark mode for your divider.

Something like:

Add at the end of your single item layout

```
   <View
       style="@style/Divider" />
```

Then in the styles file:

```
<style name="Divider">
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorDivider</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">1dp</item>
</style>
```

And depends on how you implement your dark mode, have two color files for light and dark mode, where you define your `colorDivider`

Comment: The divider is grey in normal mode, so it should be visible on a black background.